# Using Sage-provided Scipy with own python

Tags: python, linux, scipy, sage

I'm trying to install Scipy from source on Red Hat, but having some issues with the installation process, especially with ATLAS. I saw that [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/index.html) includes Scipy and Numpy along with various other packages, and requires minimal configuration. If I build Sage, will I be able to import Scipy in Sage from my original installation of Python, or do I have to do it from the Python provided with Sage?

Also, is it possible to only build specific packages within Sage and not have to build the whole thing?

The situation that I'm in requires that I build from source, so downloading a precompiled binary isn't an option.

Thanks!

Comment: if you just need scipy and don't bother about space, you may better off with one of "enthought canopy" or "continuum anaconda". You would need to use the shipped interpreter though.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you do have to use the Python provided with Sage (though that shouldn't be a problem unless you absolutely need Python 3 for something).  In fact you can do

```
sage -ipython
```

and just get IPython with the Sage version.  It is not that great to try to build only specific packages, but in principle you could probably build the Sage Python and then somehow convince the packaging system to just build Numpy/Scipy.  On the other hand, unless you have a G4 PPC Mac like the one next to me, it shouldn't take very long to build Sage (as long as you export `MAKE="make -j4"` or something).

Finally, there are some efforts to make Sage more modular in this sense.  See Sage on Gentoo and lmona.de for some examples.

Good luck!